# Django Bootstrap link won't open modal

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

When I tap the add new task button I want the modal to open, and it does in the original bootstrap file but not when I put it into django.

```
<div class="col-auto">
  <button class="btn btn-round" data-toggle="#modal" data-target="#task-add-modal">
   <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </button>
 </div>



<form class="modal fade" id="task-add-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">New Task</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close btn btn-round" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <!--end of modal head-->
```

Comment: have you included both the css and js files of bootstrap in your project?

Comment: this is how I try to include js but dosen't work:     {% load staticfiles %}
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="{% static assets/js/bootstrap.js %}"></script>

Comment: oh so it shows a 404 for these files in the inspect element console of the browser?

Comment: I get this error TemplateSyntaxError at /3/view/detail/
Could not parse the remainder: '/jquery.min.js' from 'js/jquery.min.js'

Answer (score 0):

So based on the discussion we had in the comments I feel this might be the problem with the static files not loaded properly, so from the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css) you must include static files like this,

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="{% static 'assets/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
```

I guess you forgot the quotes inside the src

Also in your `urls.py` you must include this after the `url_patterns`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib.staticfiles import views

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),

    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```